# Why is it unadvisable to run Jenkins on the same computer one develops on?

Tags: jenkins, fastlane

I have read four tutorials about getting started with Jenkins, and whilst they say it is possible to run Jenkins on the same computer on develops on they also all recommend installing it on a separate one, most commonly a Mac Mini. However: I only own a MacBook Pro; am short on cash; and am only person contributing to my iOS projects currently (I want to *learn* Jenkins for future client work). So it would be better for me for now to use my MacBook for both purposes.

Whilst I appreciate this is a matter of opinion somewhat, I am wondering what *the reason is* for the recommendation of separation, and whether I might be able to run Jenkins on the MacBook for now?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If you have a team of people it might need dedicated resources, otherwise it will slow down.

Comment: Thank you @doctolove. As this is a matter of opinion I won't be accepting any answers, but I've upvoted your comment.

Comment: To "separate" environments, you can run Jenkins in a docker container. To install docker: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/. To install the Jenkins image to run: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/

Comment: Thank you @LyndseyFerguson. As this is a matter of opinion I won't be accepting any answers, but I've upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is advised to have a master server and a number of slave server is only valid in company (or big team) environment. It is that build job can be CPU and memory intensive and often many developer starts jobs on the server. In cases like that one machine (being the master and slave server ot once) will be slow. Not only the jobs will take longer to finish, but even the web interface may become unresponsive.

For learning the basic configuration steps one machine is totally enough and you can even run your builds with your Jenkins instance.

Comment: Thank you @handras. As this is a matter of opinion I won't be accepting any answers, but I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum I wouldn't consider this a matter of opinion. The answer is totally correct and it fully answers your question. You should accept it I think.

Comment: Perhaps I should have posed the question as "Why do you think is it unadvisable to run Jenkins on the same computer one develops on?"

Comment: "My opinion is that this is not a matter of opinion" is quite funny btw. Also, have you considered that given that presumably: I do not know the answer to my question; and I don't currently work in a team (you'd be right to presume both in this case) that I am in no position to verify the comments made by @handras, ergo accepting the answer would at best be arrogant and at worse simply wrong?

Comment: I imagine that in a most cases the points @handras makes have validity and I am certainly bearing them in mind. This is very different to being "correct".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the reason for that is in those tutorials, however, I can suggest an easy way to get started with Jenkins for free (That's how I usually run jenkins for personal use). You can create a free account with one of the Cloud providers like AWS, GCP or Azure and have your jenkins running there. For example, in AWS you can have a 1-year [free trial account](https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier/) where you can spin up some free servers. There are many tutorials online, like [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/jenkins-on-aws/jenkins-on-aws.html), which will show you step by step of how to get started with Jenkins on AWS. Here are some high-level steps:

1. Create a free account in AWS (or any other cloud provider)
2. Spin up an EC2 instance - it can be any linux version or windows, whatever you are more comfortable with
3. SSH or RDP to the instance and install jenkins - there are exact installation steps for any flavor of your OS out there
4. Once the installation is complete, you will be able to access jenkins on your browser - in case of AWS, it would be the public ip of the server and default port 8080

Comment: Thank you @Petr-Hecko. As this is a matter of opinion I won't be accepting any answers, but I've upvoted your answer.